# security issues with client side code javascript and unbounce

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I am trying to integrate an unbounce account with a salesforce account, I can get the leads generated across to salesforce fine, however the form used is js, and I have the option to add custom js to the page.

What I want to do is setup hidden fields in the form that posts and then use js as custom code to extract the referrer from the url + the source from the query string and to split the 'name' field into 'firstname' 'lastname'.

What i am wondering is as this code is client side no server side option available, is it making our salesforce account vulnerable in any way?

what is the worst that can happen

disclaimer not a coder just a basic understanding
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using JavaScript to read and parse the referrer, you're just modifying information that's already in the URL. This is publicly available information, so no security vulnerability.

On the other hand, if you are accessing your SalesForce account via some sort of API or other function calls in page code, we need more details before answering your question adequately.

Answer (score 0):

The js is simply gathering data and then being submitted with the form, from what i understand the sending of the form details including the hidden fields are then done server side with ruby